# "The largest crime" or "The biggest crime"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, collocations, superlatives

English is not my first language, so sorry about my grammar. My question is which phrase is more proper?

> 1. Theft is the **largest** crime in America.

or

> 2. Theft is the **biggest** crime in America.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to say that you can't really measure crime on a simple "size" scale, so neither works; you need to establish what aspect of crime you are measuring, and then apply an appropriate adjective.  In this case I think you are referring to which crime is committed most frequently, so you might say

> Theft is the *most common* crime in America.

Depending on what else you are measuring, you may have to get very wordy; if you want to refer to how much monetary value is lost, for example, you might say

> The crime that costs its victims the most money is theft.

Comment: "Costliest" would probably work well for your second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking in terms of numbers, then largest or biggest could be used.

> Office place theft cost American companies 3 billion dollars in 2016. This dwarfed shoplifting, which in comparison, cost approximately 300 million dollars.
>
> This makes things like stealing office supplies the largest crime in corporate America.

Although in this case, I'd probably use "largest/biggest problem" or the "largest source of lost profits".

In general, largest is perhaps slightly more formal, but there's not a large/big difference between the two.